# How can I force drop a finite number of connections in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I want to be able to just force drop a bunch of connections if a server has too many connections.

Answer (score 2):

The only supported way of doing that is to have the server application itself enforce a cap on the number of connections. It can consider lifetime of the connection, how long it's been idle, and other factors in deciding which connection are the best candidates to be closed.

Closing the connection from outside of the application itself is possible through various hacks, but none of them are particular clean. And all of them suffer from the lack of any good way to pick candidates for closing.

- Use `ip6tables` (or `iptables`) to create a rule to respond with a RST packet to the next packet generated by the server for each of the connections. One drawback of this is that it won't kill idle connections. If the application configures keepalives (which it should), then even idle connections will be killed eventually, but quickly shutting down idle connections isn't possible through this approach.
- Temporarily add the IP address of a client to the `dummy0` network interface. Then open a new connection with the exact same client IP and port number to the server which will replace the old one. You can use the `nc` command to create such a connection. Once you kill `nc` again the old and new connections will both be gone. Then remove the IP address from the `dummy0` interface again. A drawback of this method is that while you are doing it you will break all communication with that remote IP address which can cause problem for unrelated connections.
- If the server application uses a process per connection model you can kill individual child processes to shut down connections. This however can prevent the server application from properly cleaning up and will likely mess with your logging.
- Use a tool to spoof RST packets. The first spoofed RST packet will not be honored due to an incorrect sequence number, but it will produce a challenge packet containing information about the correct sequence number which can then be used to produce a proper RST packet.